# Where can I find the latest METAR and TAF for RPVK / Kalibo International Airport?

Tags: metar

What website holds the latest METAR and TAF for RPVK / Philippine weather?
In aviation weather the information does not exist at all times.

Could you suggest an other website that provides the required information.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You can use the [OGIMET database](https://www.ogimet.com/metars.phtml.en), but they only have one TAF for RPVK in the last 24 hours

Comment: Interestingly, the Philippine weather service [only provides TAFs](http://bagong.pagasa.dost.gov.ph/aviation) on their site. I don't know what to make of that.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the latest METAR for RPVK here: https://tgftp.nws.noaa.gov/data/observations/metar/stations/RPVK.TXT and TAF here: https://tgftp.nws.noaa.gov/data/forecasts/taf/stations/RPVK.TXT

Remember to look at the publication date/time, since it may not be very recent.